# Accessing elements of a map of maps using a string in Groovy

Tags: dictionary, groovy

Given I have a map like:

```
def myMap = [ b : [ c:"X" ] ]
```

And a string

```
def key = 'b.c'
```

I'd like to see my options for using the key to get to the value 'X'.

I have come up with two ways of achieving this myself, but I am not very happy with these solutions:

```
 1) Eval.me("theMap", myMap, "theMap.$key")
 2) mayMap."$key.split('\\.')[0]"."$key.split('\\.')[1]"
```

Anyone has a better way of doing this in Groovy?

Comment: Was the answer helpful in any ways? If yes, can it be accepted for others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A convenient way is to use [ConfigObject](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigObject.html) which implements Map.

```
def myMap = [b:[c:'X', d: 'Y'], a:[n:[m:[x:'Y']]]] as ConfigObject
def props = myMap.toProperties()

assert props['b.c'] == 'X'
assert props.'b.c' == 'X'
assert props.'a.n.m.x' == 'Y'
```

**Pros:**

- No more splitting.
- No more evaluating.

Comment: It should be noted that this seems to only work when the values are Strings; attempting this with a List of HashMap's and the `toProperties()` method converts the List into a String containing `toString()` versions of the HashMap's.

Comment: I didn't understand what advantage does it give compare to use `myMap['b.c']` ?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO its not the `ConfigObject`, that does the trick, its the `Properties` (from `ConfigObject.toProperties()`). Look & try:

```
def props = new ConfigSlurper().parse("""
b {
 c = 'X'
 d = 'Y'
}
a {
 n {
   m {
     x:'Y'
   }
 }
}""")

assert props['b.c'] == 'X'
assert props.'b.c' == 'X'
assert props.'a.n.m.x' == 'Y'
'passed'
```

Assertion failed:

```
assert props['b.c'] == 'X'
       |    |       |
       |    [:]     false
       [b:[c:X, d:Y], a:[n:[m:[:]]], b.c:[:]]

    at ConsoleScript7.run(ConsoleScript7:14)
```

and I really wish, the `ConfigObject` could be indexed with such combined keys like above