# Access Map inside Map

Tags: groovy

I have seen a lot of questions/answers regarding map inside map.
However, I am using Groovy and smart things IDE. I have tried the following ways before but unsuccessful.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437561/accessing-elements-of-a-map-of-maps-using-a-string-in-groovy](https://community.smartthings.com/t/philips-hue-bloom-and-hub-v1/32109)

The map is as follow :

```
[8: [**id:8, name:Hue bloom 1,
     hub:c2adc24b-39a1-41b8-9657-31422c7ecb02, type:Color light**] ]
```

I need the hub value.

```
c2adc24b-39a1-41b8-9657-31422c7ecb02
```

Any help/suggestion is welcome. Thanks. [My question on the smartthings community.](https://community.smartthings.com/t/philips-hue-bloom-and-hub-v1/32109)

Comment: it's either `m[8]["hub"]` or `m["8"]["hub"]` - depending on the types

Comment: `m[ 8 ].hub` would do

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot guys. I was in such a hurry that I couldn't think anymore. Now,when I calm myself down and read through things carefully. It's all clear and very simple.